# Newtons Method finding cube root, answer comes out as 0 every time

Tags: c++, newtons-method

I am using a program with C++ that will calculate the cube root of a given float point number using Newton Methods. My program compiles, but the answer always comes out to zero. Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double epsilon = 0.00000001;
    double A = 0;
    double x1 = A / 10;
    double x2 = 0;
    int iter = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a number to square. " << endl;
    cin >> A;

    while ((fabs(x1 - x2) > epsilon) && (iter < 100)) {
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = ((2 / 3 * x1) + (A / (3 * x1 * x1)));
        ++iter;
    }

    cout << "The answer is : " << x2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: `2/3` is done as integer math. And so is 0. Try making it `2.0/3.0`

Comment: You never enter you while loop.

Comment: *My program compiles* -- A program compiling ok only means that the syntax is correct.  It has no bearing on whether the program will run correctly or give the correct results.

Comment: do `std::cout << (2/3);` and watch the magic

Comment: also, `x1 = A / 10` is equal to zero becuase `A` is zero

Comment: `fabs(x1 - x2)` is zero the first time through.

Comment: Mike: thanks for catching the integer math, fixed it but still didnt work.

Comment: Jarvis, I dont mean to come off as rude, but how do I not enter it? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Nathan: Where should I insert that at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were assigning variables to be zero, so you weren't going into the loop and you were also dividing by zero because you set `x1=x2` and along with what was said in the comments to your post. So I moved some assigning and declarations and everything worked out fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double epsilon = 0.00000001;
    double A = 0;
    double x1 = 0;
    double x2 = 1;
    int iter = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a number to square. " << endl;
    cin >> A;
    x1 = A / 10.0;
    while ((fabs(x1 - x2) > epsilon) && (iter < 100)) {
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = ((2.0 / 3.0 * x1) + (A / (3.0 * x1 * x1)));
        ++iter;
    }

    cout << "The answer is : " << x2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. It was just that small difference with setting x1 = x2 and all. Thanks again!

Comment: happy I could help sus the bug.