# Function for Newton's Method in C++

Tags: c++

I am getting back into programming after twenty years. I was a good C programmer then, so I am jumping in with C++. For my first project, I am writing a function to calculate a cube root using Newton's Method.

Instead of converging on the answer, it just keeps approaching zero. Since it was so small, I figured it was easier to print out step by step values rather than use the debugger.

I am using Visual C++, with Visual Studio.

Here is the entire function:

```
double CalcCube(double xx, double guess)
 {
        int ii = 0;
        double result, resbuff;


        for (ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
        {
            resbuff =  guess - (pow(guess,3) / (3*guess*guess));
            cout << "Resbuff = " << resbuff << endl;
            cout << "Guess = " << guess << endl;
            guess = resbuff;
        }
      
        result = guess;
        return result;
}`
`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newtons Method finding cube root, answer comes out as 0 every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143508/newtons-method-finding-cube-root-answer-comes-out-as-0-every-time)

Comment: What role does the argument `xx` have? How do you call thisfubction? What are the values you pass to it? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (you can hard-code the "input").

Comment: WIth what values are you calling the function? It will be helpful to get a [mcve] instead of just the function.

Comment: *"Instead of converging on the answer, it just keeps approaching zero"* -- this does not describe a problem if the answer is zero (the cube root of zero). What was your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong equation used**

Newton's Method finds the value of `x` such that `f(x) = 0`.

Code is solving `0 = x*x*x`, which the answer is `x = 0`.

```
//                      x*x*x
// resbuff =  guess - (pow(guess,3) / (3*guess*guess));
```

The zero being sought is the solution to `0 = y - x*x*x`

```
resbuff =  guess - (xx - pow(guess,3) / (3*guess*guess));
//                  y  - x*x*x
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the math:

```
pow(guess,3) / (3*guess*guess) = guess^3 / 3*guess^2 = guess/3  
=>  resbuf= guess - guess/3
```

So in each iteration you get an smaller value, tending to 0

Answer (score 0):

The equation for computing cube root using the Newton Raphson method is (from https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-use-newton-s-method-to-approximate-the-value-of-cube-root)

```
xn1 = xn - (x - xn^3)/3*xn^2
```

By using

```
resbuff =  guess - (pow(guess,3) / (3*guess*guess));
```

you are computing the cube root of zero. That's why you are getting zero as your answer.

Change that line to

```
resbuff =  guess - (xx - pow(guess,3)) / (3*guess*guess));
```

to get the correct answer.